# parsing json image

Tags: objective-c

I'm parsing my data on this way:

```
 NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"description"]];
```

But is there a way to parse an cell image? Normally it's

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
```

But i'm searching for a way like

```
[[cell UIImage cellimage] ....
```

Something like that so i can parse an image url from json in it

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];  
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Set a max width for the image

Comment: This will block the main thread due to the synchronous URL request, which is always a bad thing to do, since the UI won't respond until the request is complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar                     // called when keyboard search button pressed
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.hidden=NO;

    NSLog( @" Searchbar text  =   %@",searchBar.text);
    strSearch=searchBar.text;
    strSearch=[strSearch stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [self searchGooglePhotos];

}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar                    // called when cancel button pressed

{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
-(void)searchGooglePhotos
{

    // Build the string to call the Flickr API
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=%@",strSearch];

    NSLog(@"urlarrystring is  := %@",urlString);
    // Create NSURL string from formatted string
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    // Setup and start async download
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection release];
    [request release];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{


    // Store incoming data into a string
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Create a dictionary from the JSON string
    NSDictionary *respone = [jsonString JSONValue];
    //NSLog(@"result dict is :%@",respone);

    // Build an array from the dictionary for easy access to each entry
    urlarry = [[[respone valueForKey:@"responseData"] valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"url"];
    NSArray *title = [[[respone valueForKey:@"responseData"] valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"title"];
    MoreUrlarry=[[[respone valueForKey:@"responseData"] valueForKey:@"cursor"]valueForKey:@"moreResultsUrl"];
    [urlarry retain];
    NSLog(@"photourlarry is :%@",urlarry);
    NSLog(@"phototitle is :%@",title);
    NSLog(@"photoMoreUrlarry is :%@",MoreUrlarry);

    NSData *data2;

    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] init];
    [scrl removeFromSuperview];
    [displayview removeFromSuperview];
    scrl=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44,320, 430)];
    [scrl setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320*[urlarry count], 430)];
    scrl.pagingEnabled=YES;

    //==========

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Assign activity indicator to the pre-defined property (so it can be removed when image loaded)
    //self.activityIndicator =  [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 67, 25, 25)];  

    // Start it animating and add it to the view

    // Create multiple imageviews to simulate a 'real' application with multiple images
    CGFloat verticalPosition = 10;
    int i = 1;
    for (i=1; i<5; i++) {

        // Set vertical position of image in view.
        if (i > 1) {
            verticalPosition = verticalPosition+85;
        }

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(122, verticalPosition, 80, 80)];  
        imageView.tag = i;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];

        // set the image to be loaded (using the same one here but could/would be different)

        NSString *str123=[urlarry objectAtIndex:i-1];



        NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str123];

        // Create an array with the URL and imageView tag to 
        // reference the correct imageView in background thread.
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imgURL, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i], nil  ];

        // Start a background thread by calling method to load the image
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:arr];

    }
    [pool release]; 
    /*

    int x=10,y=50,p=250,q=20;
    for (int i=0; i<[urlarry count]; i++)
    {

        str=[NSString stringWithString:[urlarry objectAtIndex:i]];
        data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
        Favimage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data2];

        markButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [markButton setFrame:CGRectMake(p, q, 35,20)];
        markButton.tag=i;
        NSLog(@"tag is :%d",markButton.tag);
        //[imgButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //imgButton.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        //  [imgButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[imgButton setImage:[Favimage imageScaledToFitSize:CGSizeMake(300, 320)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [markButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mark_buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [scrl addSubview:markButton];


        UIButton *imgButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [imgButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 300,320)];
        imgButton.tag=i;
        NSLog(@"tag is :%d",imgButton.tag);
    //[imgButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        imgButton.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    //  [imgButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imgButton setImage:[Favimage imageScaledToFitSize:CGSizeMake(300, 320)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imgButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[imgButton setImage:Favimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [scrl addSubview:imgButton];

        //UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 90, 90)];
//      [imageview setImage:Favimage];
//      [scrl addSubview:imageview];


        NSLog(@"value of x=%d",x);
        NSLog(@"value of y=%d",y);

        NSLog(@"value of p=%d",p);
        NSLog(@"value of q=%d",q);
        NSLog(@"str is : %@",str);

        if (y>=30 ) 
        {
            //x=15;
            x=x+320;
        }
        if (q>=0 ) 
        {
            //x=15;
            p=p+320;
        }
        //else 
//      {
//          y=y+;
    //  }



    }*/
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    spinner.hidden=TRUE;
    [self.view addSubview:scrl];
    btnmore.hidden=NO;

    //NSLog(@"str is : %@",str);
//  NSLog(@"j is : %d",j);
//  NSLog(@"p is : %d",p);


}

- (void) loadImageInBackground:(NSArray *)urlAndTagReference  {

    NSLog(@"Received URL for tagID: %@", urlAndTagReference);

    // Create a pool
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Retrieve the remote image. Retrieve the imgURL from the passed in array
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]];
    UIImage *img    = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

    // Create an array with the URL and imageView tag to 
    // reference the correct imageView in background thread.
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img, [urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1], nil  ];

    // Image retrieved, call main thread method to update image, passing it the downloaded UIImage
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignImageToImageView:) withObject:arr waitUntilDone:YES];

}

- (void) assignImageToImageView:(NSArray *)imgAndTagReference
{

    // Create a pool
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // loop
    for (UIImageView *checkView in [self.view subviews] ) {
        NSLog(@"Checking tag: %d against passed in tag %d",[checkView tag], [[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1] intValue]);
        if ([checkView tag] == [[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:1] intValue]) {

            // Found imageView from tag, update with img
            [checkView setImage:[imgAndTagReference objectAtIndex:0]];

            //set contentMode to scale aspect to fit
            checkView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            //change width of frame
            CGRect frame = checkView.frame;
            frame.size.width = 80;
            checkView.frame = frame;

        }
    }   

    // release the pool
    [pool release];

    // Remove the activity indicator created in ViewDidLoad()
    //[self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

}

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *imgButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    int q=imgButton.tag;

    string=[[NSString alloc] init];
    string=[NSString stringWithString:[urlarry objectAtIndex:q]];

//  NSLog(@"aap str is :%@",appDel.appstr);
//  [self.navigationController pushViewController:objimv animated:YES];

}
```